# Can't find variable: __TEST__

Tags: javascript, npm, nativescript, angular-nativescript

I'm new at Nativescript. Whenever I try to compile a project on my iPhone; It gives me this exception.

My phone on 14.0 and Nativescript on 7.0.11

Log is there:

```
2020-12-01 00:12:26.786 nsplaydev[49332:2731673] JavaScript error:  
file:///app/tns_modules/react-nativescript/dist/nativescript-vue-next/runtime/registry.js:61:14: JS ERROR  
 ReferenceError: Can't find variable: _TEST_  
2020-12-01 00:12:26.788 nsplaydev[49332:2731673] PlayLiveSync: Uncaught Exception    
NativeScript encountered a fatal error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: _TEST_  
 at   
anonymous(file:///app/tns_modules/react-nativescript/dist/nativescript-vue-next/runtime/registry.js:61:14)
```